# How do I get access to this nested data?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

Hey so I'm using a for loop trying to get the tracks that are associated with each playlist and I am struggling. It appears to work in the console but when I append it, I just get [object, Object] can anybody help me with this please? Sorry for the newbie question, I'm still trying to get used to and understand JS better and i'm especially not good with loops just yet. Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

PS. I am using rails for the backend.

This is the output of `console.log`

```
Array(2), "Country Songs"]0: Array(2)0: {id: 2, title: "Fourth Song", artist: "Kristy", created_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.144Z", updated_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.144Z", …}1: {id: 4, title: "First Song", artist: "Randy", created_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.219Z", updated_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.219Z", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)1: "Country Songs"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

```
function getPlaylists() {
  fetch(BACKEND_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(list => {
      list.data.forEach(playlist => {

        let newPlaylist = new Playlist(playlist, playlist.attributes);
        let trackDetails = [playlist.attributes.tracks, playlist.attributes.name];

        let i;
        let t;
        for (i = 0; i < playlist.attributes.tracks; i++) {
          playlist.attributes.tracks[i].artist, playlist.attributes.tracks[i].title
        }
        console.log(trackDetails)
        document.getElementById("playlist-container").innerHTML += newPlaylist.renderPlaylistCard();
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your `for` loop?

Comment: I'm trying to get the titles and artists of all tracks.

Comment: Right, but there's no assignment or any processing there. You're just accessing the track artist and title without doing anything. What's your expected output here?

Comment: so I've only done half of the work basically, I need to do something with it now like push it?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your expected output is. In a `for` loop you do something with the data, please update with what your expected output is.

Comment: @Phix My expected output would basically just be like what you see in the question from the console.log, it would be something like this although I don't need the created and updated_at;
```Array(2), "Country Songs"]0: Array(2)0: {id: 2, title: "Fourth Song", artist: "Kristy", created_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.144Z", updated_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.144Z", …}1: {id: 4, title: "First Song", artist: "Randy", created_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.219Z", updated_at: "2020-06-30T23:52:06.219Z", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)1: "Country Songs"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)